# How to properly set focus owner

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, focus

This is my first time trying to set the focus owner, but my understanding is that my computer's keyboard will communicate with the Object in focus.

My class InstrumentHandler extends JFrame and has a field called instrument.
My class Instrument extends JPanel and implements KeyListener.

These are the last 5 lines of my InstrumentHandler constructor.

```
    instrument.setRequestFocusEnabled(true);
    instrument.requestFocus();
    instrument.requestFocusInWindow();
    instrument.grabFocus();
    System.out.println(instrument.isFocusOwner());
```

Why does it print false?! An additional question is, why didn't java just make a setFocusOwner method?!

Comment: *"why didn't java just make a setFocusOwner method?!"* - Because every OS has different requirements about how and when a component can become focus - welcome to the wonderful world of abstraction.  Based on the documentation `instrument.requestFocusInWindow` is generally the preferred method for requesting focus now days - why it would not work is typically platform dependent, but, the component must be realised (attached to a native peer) of a container capable of been focused

Comment: Thanks! Your advice to use a native peer worked. I now declare `JPanel instrumentPanel = new Instrument()` .Functionally, my program works fine now! However, I am curious as to why `System.out.println(instrumentPanel.isFocusOwner())` still prints false?

Comment: It's a matter of timing, it's possible, even though you've requested it, the component has not received focus. Use a `FocusListener` if it's important

Comment: Just for reference, some window systems assign focus to whatever GUI element the mouse is hovering over.  For someone to forcibly grab focus on such a platform, Java would have to move the mouse pointer as well...and that would feel really strange to users of that platform.  Hence, Java lets you request focus, but may not give it to you... So even your new method, properly attached to a native peer, may still fail to receive focus.